# How to decompress gzip containing multiple files?

Tags: c++, boost, gzip, zlib

Is there an option, using zlib or boost, to unpack a gzip archive containing several files?
All options which I figured out were for 1 single file in archive.

I know about minizip, quazip and other useful libs, but I need to try to find an option without additional libraries.

Comment: Doesn't gzip itself support a single file and use tar for multiple files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gzip doesn't compress multiple files. It only compresses one file. The reason you can't find a way to extract gzip archives is that they don't exist.